# Do all Aurora RDS events get sent to CloudWatch Events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora

I created a CloudWatch Event Rule intended to send notifications when our Aurora clusters failed over. We then had a (manual) failover in our staging environment, but the rule didn't capture any events related to that failover as I expected.

This is the pattern that I used:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.rds"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "RDS DB Instance Event"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "EventCategories": [
      "failover"
    ]
  }
}
```

This pattern *does* generate a "sample event" in the rule editor within the web console, so it seems valid, but is there something that I need to do in order to get these particular events shipped to CloudWatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the correct `detail-type` for Aurora failovers is `"RDS DB Cluster Event"` rather than `"RDS DB Instance Event"`. The latter generates sample data in the editor, whereas the former does not, but that seems to be a bug.

Comment: Glad you found your answer. Those events lack documentation, and often times only apply reactively (failover already occurred). There's a bunch of things you can catch in RDS that will indicate failure is imminent. Most people don't monitor them, even though they're right in Cloudwatch. Here's a guide for the most common ones. https://www.bluematador.com/blog/how-to-monitor-amazon-rds-with-cloudwatch?utm_source=stack-overflow&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=social-share